# typo in equation of quadrifolium? $(x^2 + y^2) = (x^2 - y^2)^2$

Tags: polar-coordinates

I wanted to draw a rose curve: $r = \cos 2\theta $ then if I wanted to write the equation in Cartesian coordinates:
$$ \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = x^2 - y^2 \text{ or } x^2 + y^2 = (x^2 - y^2)^2  $$
Except this is not the case in fact the Wikipedia page gives a cube on the left side.  And I wonder why that is:
$$  (x^2 + y^2)^3 = (x^2 - y^2)^2 $$
Is there an algebra mistake on my part?

[image]

Comment: It is possible to draw a straight line through the graph and cut it at 6 points. That means the equation of this graph is at least of degree $6$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=r=\cos2\theta=\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta=\frac{x^2-y^2}{r^2}$. It all trickles down from your forgetting an $r^{-2}$ factor there.